# How do I loop until array list quota is met

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I am trying to get this program to loop over and over until the sum of the doubles in the arraylist equal to 100. Basically I want users to enter in any numbers but once it hits 100 then it wont add anymore. Or if they add a 50 and then try to add a 51 it will tell them its over 100. I have tried many different loops but I still cant get it to work properly. I just need a steer in the right direction.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<double> myList = new List<double>();
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
                myList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));

            } while (myList.Sum() >= 100);
            double sum = myList.Sum();
            Console.WriteLine("The sum is " + sum);

            double avg = sum / myList.Count;
            Console.WriteLine("The average is " + avg);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _array list quota is met_ What is that mean?

Comment: do you mean `while(myList.Sum() < 100)`? Why are you iterating if the number of elements is greater than 100? Or you want to make them add 100 numbers? The question is not really clear.

Comment: I want the array list sum to get no larger then 100.

Comment: Then do exactly that, check if the array list sum is no larger than 100 (with `myList.Sum() < 100`), you don't need to count how many items there is

Comment: @user2932460 `.Count` is the number of items in the array, not the sum...

Comment: Shouldn't you set i, which is your control variable, inside your while loop

Comment: you add it before you check if it's over 100

Comment: Okay.. so when do you even want the execution of this program to stop? When the number is exactly equal to 100... or when the number goes higher than 100 or what?

Comment: I updated the code to what I am currently working with. Right now when I run the program no matter what integer I enter it doesn't loop. I enter a 150 and it will tell me the sum and average. If I enter a 1 it tells me the sum and average. It should loop until sum is 100 or more.

Comment: What's actually wrong with your code?  does it throw a `DoesNotWorkException`?

Comment: I added my previous suggestions with a code example, you can find it below.

Answer (score 0):

Check the sum of the numbers inside your loop, and write the message if the sum exceeds your quota:

```
double sum = 0.0;
bool continue = true;
do
{
    Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input.Length > 0)
    {
        double next = Convert.ToDouble(input);
        if (sum + next <= 100)
        {
            sum += next;
            myList.Add(next);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input exceeds quota.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        continue = false;
    }
} while (continue);
```

Some things to note about this code:

- This will continue to read input until the user simply presses return without any input.
- Rather than recalculate the sum on every iteration, I use a local variable.
- It allows the user to enter a new value, and if it exceeds the quota, enter a smaller value instead.

Answer (score 0):

This would read all numbers that are entered and add them together. Once the sum is greater than (or equal to 100), it will exit.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<double> myList = new List<double>();
    var sum = 0;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
        myList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));

        sum = myList.Sum();

        if (sum > 100)
        {
            Console.Write("Your sum is greater than 100.");
        }
    } while (sum <= 100)

    Console.WriteLine("The sum is " + sum);

    double avg = sum / myList.Count;
    Console.WriteLine("The average is " + avg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop while your sum of 100 isn't achieved, so the condition is `inputList.Sum() < 100`.

If the sum and new number is greater than 100, you tell the user. If it's not the case, then you can add them together.

Also, you should query the user for an `int`, unless you really need a decimal number (if it's the case you'll need to check the equality with an epsilon, decimals and 'exactly equal' do not fit together well).

This gives the following :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> inputList = new List<int>();

    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
        int numberToAdd = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (numberToAdd + inputList.Sum() > 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number will not be added, {0} is greater than 100", numberToAdd + inputList.Sum());
        }
        else
        {
            inputList.Add(numberToAdd);
        }

    } while (inputList.Sum() < 100);

    double sum = inputList.Sum();
    Console.WriteLine("The sum is " + sum);

    double avg = sum / inputList.Count;
    Console.WriteLine("The average is " + avg);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

Once cleaned a bit :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> inputList = AskUserForInput();
        PrintSum(inputList);
        PrintAverage(inputList);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<int> AskUserForInput()
    {
        List<int> inputList = new List<int>();

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
            int numberToAdd = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (IsGreaterThan100(numberToAdd, inputList))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number will not be added, {0} is greater than 100", numberToAdd + inputList.Sum());
            }
            else
            {
                inputList.Add(numberToAdd);
            }
        } while (IsSumLowerThan100(inputList));

        return inputList;
    }

    private static bool IsGreaterThan100(int numberToAdd, List<int> inputList)
    {
        return numberToAdd + inputList.Sum() > 100;
    }

    private static bool IsSumLowerThan100(List<int> inputList)
    {
        return inputList.Sum() < 100;
    }

    private static void PrintAverage(List<int> inputList)
    {
        double avg = inputList.Sum() / inputList.Count;
        Console.WriteLine("The average is " + avg);
    }

    private static void PrintSum(List<int> inputList)
    {
        double sum = inputList.Sum();
        Console.WriteLine("The sum is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: This uses Integer when I need it to be a double.

Comment: As I said, you can very easily switch to double but you'll need to use an epsilon for the equality checks, because you're playing with fractions (1 + 2 can equal 3.000001 instead of 3)

Comment: I have no clue what epsilon checks are. Any chance I can do floats without that? I just need to use floating point numbers for this.

Comment: Basically you have to check if a - b is nearly equal to 0, instead of checking if a == b. Here's a [link](http://csharp.2000things.com/2011/09/21/416-use-an-epsilon-to-compare-two-floating-point-numbers/) that explains it a bit more, and a language-agnostic detailed explanation [here](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

your loop needs to look more like this

```
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your number: ");

        double num = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if ((myList.Sum() + num) <= 100)
            myList.Add(num);
        else
            break;

    } while (true);
```

you'll need to modify it as I'm unclear on your exact requirements, but it's a start

Answer (score 0):

try this Loop:

```
     while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
            double temp = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            if (myList.Sum() + temp <= 100)
            {
                myList.Add(temp);
                if (myList.Sum() >= 100)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("You Exceed The Limit ");
            }
        }
```